# 765 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream

Tags: nginx, mediawiki, php

```
2014/03/31 23:06:50 [error] 25914#0: *765 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 173.77.251.136, server: wiki.resonant-rise.com, request: "POST /index.php?title=Chisel&action=submit HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9016", host: "wiki.resonant-rise.com", referrer: "http://wiki.resonant-rise.com/index.php?title=Chisel&action=edit"
2014/03/31 23:06:50 [error] 25914#0: *765 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 173.77.251.136, server: wiki.resonant-rise.com, request: "POST /index.php?title=Chisel&action=submit HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9016", host: "wiki.resonant-rise.com", referrer: "http://wiki.resonant-rise.com/index.php?title=Chisel&action=edit"
```

I have a mediawiki installation and an IPB installation. They both through up errors but this one error from mediawiki prevents me from posting semi-large articles. I have tried a lot of the solutions out there, adding catch_workers_output = yes, adjusting pm.* settings. Still not able to resolve this issue. I am coming to my wits end trying to figure this one out.

PHP-FPM Conf

http://pastie.org/private/aczklc52ll9yv0uz5drcqg

PHP-FPM WWW.CONF

http://pastie.org/private/wod3xipxhm8ractksw7ha

NGINX VHOST for MEDIAWIKI

http://pastie.org/private/h9co8aykbdmfzk2bd5qq

Comment: All links are lost

Answer (score 0):

If the failure depends on size of the pages, it has to do with how much work the operation causes. My wild guess would be: increase the timeout (you currently have `send_timeout          60s;`).

It's easy for the parse time of a very long page to go over 60 seconds, especially if you're on a low power server, have not [tuned performance](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Performance_tuning) or have enabled heavy parser extensions.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was that the php version of the project was different with the version of php I had been

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).